# Postfix to Infix conversion in C

Tags: c, data-structures, stack, postfix-notation

Can anyone help me with Postfix to Infix conversion in C?

I know the algorithm, it's something like:

- Take the expression as input
- if the char is an operand, then push it into the stack
- if the char is an operator, then continuously pop two elements from the stack, place the operator between them, and then push the resultant expression into the stack
- Do the above steps until the whole expression is not read.

```
#include<stdio.h>

char st[100];
int top = -1;

void push(char el)
{
  st[++top] = el; 
}

char pop()
{
  return st[top--];
}

int isop(char val)
{
  if (val == '+' || val == '-' || val == '*' || val == '/' || val == '%')
  {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
void main()
{
  char exp[50], v1, v2, ex;
  int i = 0;

  printf("Enter the expression: ");
  gets(exp);

  while(exp[i] != '\0')
  {
    if(isop(exp[i]))
    {
      v1 = pop();
      v2 = pop();
      ex = exp[i];

    } else {
      push(exp[i]);
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```

The only place where I am stuck at is, how will I push the resultant expression (expression obtained by placing the operator in between the two popped operands) again into the stack.

Comment: In what form do you want the infix expression? As a character string? As a parse tree? As a linked list of tokens? That will definitely condition the answer (although all the answers are some variation of "Pop the top two elements on the stack, combine them with the operator into a combined expression, and push that on the stack." Also, do you care about being able to evaluate the infix expression? Because if you do, and you need the value to be correct, you'll probably need to insert parentheses in some cases (or in all cases, if you're not required to produce the smallest result.)

Comment: @rici I want the infix expression as a character string

Comment: The word is 'algorithm', not 'algo', It is somebody's name.

Comment: Your stack contains (only) single characters, while an expression will be a string, so you can't push it on the stack.  You need a stack of strings for this, not a stack of characters.  You probably also need precedence info (to know when to add parenthesis), so maybe a stack of (string, precedence) pairs.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node *createNode();
void push(struct node *);
struct node *pop();
void infixConvert(char []);
void display(struct node *);
struct node {
    char ch;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}*stack[11];
int top=11;
void main() {
    char expr[25];
    printf("Enter the Expression : ");
    scanf("%s",expr);
    infixConvert(expr);
    printf("Infix Expression : ");
    display(pop(top));
}
struct node *createNode() {
    struct node *newnode;
    newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    return newnode;
}
void infixConvert(char expr[]) {
    struct node *op1, *op2;
    struct node *newnode;
    int i;
    for(i=0;expr[i]!='\0';i++) {
        if(expr[i]>='a'&&expr[i]<='z'||expr[i]>='A'&&expr[i]<='Z') {
            newnode=createNode();
            newnode->ch=expr[i];
            newnode->left=NULL;
            newnode->right=NULL;
            push(newnode);
        }
        else if(expr[i]=='+'||expr[i]=='-'||expr[i]=='*'||expr[i]=='/'||expr[i]=='^') {
            op1=pop();
            op2=pop();
            newnode=createNode();
            newnode->ch=expr[i];
            newnode->right=op1;
            newnode->left=op2;
            push(newnode);
        }
    }
}
void push(struct node *ch) {
    if(top<=0) {
        printf("Full Stack");
        return;
    }
    stack[top]=ch;
    top--;
}
struct node *pop() {
    if(top>=11) {
        printf("Stack Empty");
    }
    else {
        return stack[++top];
    }
}
void display(struct node *temp) {
    if(temp==NULL) {
        return;
    }
    display(temp->left);
    printf("%c",temp->ch);
    display(temp->right);
}
```

Comment: Mere code is not an answer. You have to explain.